# does inverse of continuous function is also continuous?

Tags: calculus, functions

Suppose that $f:R\rightarrow R $ is continuous and does have an inverse function.
How can I prove that $f^{-1}$ is also continuous?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/541082/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2067813/42969.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/68800/8157)